# Azure devops mac agent in AzureVM

Tags: macos, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We are trying to setup a self-hosted MAC OS vm for ios app builds using xcode and couldn't find any OS from Microsoft to setup the build agent in VM. Is there any way to create IOS based image for mac build to make the ios builds for Azure devops server?

Comment: You're looking for this or something else? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/osx-agent?view=azure-devops your question is bit unclear

Comment: We have standalone macOS agent. But couldn't find any virtual machines available from Microsoft side to run the macos agent in cloud. It should be self-hosted and not Microsoft hosted one.

Comment: Please note that `Azure DevOps` itself does not provide VM service. And the Mac machine provider doesn't have to be Microsoft. By the way, I don't think `Azure VM` supports MACOS images.

Comment: Agreed But checking for some options, whether we can run any azure service to do xcode builds, like we have k8s managed ado agents. if aks support macos pools

Comment: So you're not actually asking about DevOps agent, but you're asking where to find a macos VM?

Comment: yes.. a  cloud providing solution to run ios build from ado pipelines (but selfhosted)

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to test with the other cloud solution that provides MacOS VM? May I know if the answer below can solve your concerns?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, But we don't have any other cloud providers and looking for azure native solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Azure DevOps` itself, it is not a VM provider. As of now, `Azure VM` does not support provision of MacOS VMs.

In addition, I don't believe AKS/ACR is an option, since according to the documents below,

[Run a self-hosted agent in Docker - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)

> You can set up a self-hosted agent in Azure Pipelines to run inside a Windows Server Core (for Windows hosts), or Ubuntu container (for Linux hosts) with Docker.

[Container Jobs in Azure Pipelines and TFS - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops)

> On Linux and Windows agents, jobs may be run on the host or in a container. (On macOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, container jobs are not available.)

As far as I know, other Microsoft services don't provide MacOS VMs, either. For this, you can submit feedback/suggestion directly through the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#home) or via [Azure Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/ct-p/Azure)
[image]

Still, the VM provider doesn't have to be Microsoft. Therefore, you may test with [AWS MAC](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/) or [MacinCloud](https://checkout.macincloud.com/).

[MacinCloud](https://checkout.macincloud.com/) even has a plan for Azure pipelines.
[image]

Hope the information could help.